# sencha touch filter store from a list?

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, sencha-touch, store

Iam trying to apply several filter which I get from a localStorage store.

I load the store and can apply some filters:

```
var newsStore = Ext.getStore("cityStore");

newsStore.filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
  filterFn: function(item) {
    return item.get('name') == 'city1' || item.get('name') == 'city2';  
}
}));
```

But now I have a list of items and would like to iterate through all items in the list and apply them to the store filter.

The problem is imho that I cannot iterate though a loop and do return item.get('name') == 'variable' again and again because this would only filter for the last return but I would like to apply every item in the list as the filter seen above.

Hope I can find some help here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imaging you have an array containing the names you have to use for filtering the store, we will call this array 'names':

```
var names = ['Lucas', 'Pablo', 'Noelia'];
```

What you have to do in your filterFn is return true if the record contains **some** of the values listed in your **names** array. The magic is in the **some** function.

```
store.filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
  filterFn: function(item) {
      return names.some(function(name){ return name === item.get('name')});  
  }
}));
```

For example, the following store will only contain 2 rows (after apply the filter): Lucas and Pablo:

```
var names = ['Lucas', 'Pablo', 'Noelia'];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: ['id', 'name'],    
    data: [
        [ 1, 'Lucas' ],
        [ 2, 'Pablo' ],
        [ 3, 'Francisco' ]
    ]
});

store.filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
  filterFn: function(item) {
      return names.some(function(name){ return name === item.get('name')});  
}
}));

// display the filtered record in the console
store.each(function(record){ console.log(record.get('name'))})​
```

You also can do it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/5TWq9/3/

I hope this is useful. 
Good luck!

Comment: I did not work on this project for a while but I tried it again and it works! Thanks a lot!